# Create regex with reserved characters from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to create a regex using the RegExp constructor based on an array of punctuation characters as such:

`const punctuation = ['?', '.', '+'];` etc...

Then use it as such:

```
_.each(punctuation, (character) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(character, 'g');
    // do something with regex
});
```

As `?` and `+` are reserved for regex I need to escape them - I assumed this would be pretty straight forward using `escape()` or simply adding a backslash but I'm not able to make this work at all.

I get this error: `Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Escape the backslash in string `\\\`.

Comment: thansk @destoryer but that also throws a syntax error: `Invalid regular expression: /\/: \ at end of pattern`

Comment: `new RegExp("\\?").test("?")` should work.

Comment: In this case `new RegExp("\\" + character, 'g');`

Comment: @revo thank you - exactly what I needed, seems so simple now... #longday

Answer (score 2):

escape them with double blackslash, your code will become:

```
const punctuation = ['\\?', '\\.', '\\+'];

_.each(punctuation, (character) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(character, 'g');
    // do something with regex
});
```

Comment: thank you - great suggestion but not exactly what I need as I want to use the punctuation array for various purposes, not just regex. revo's answer above helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case that you have single characters in your array you could do:

```
new RegExp("\\" + character, 'g');
```